# Why does the documentation says that some WPF classes are supported under windows 8 when they are not?

Tags: .net, windows-8

I am trying to adapt some methods from WPF to Windows 8.

A lot of classes is missing in windows 8, and most of the time when I'm looking at them on the internet for an equivalent it is said that it is available for Windows 8.

Just two examples but I have seen hundred of it  :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

It is said "supported in Windows 8" at the bottom of the page. And the .Net framework supported is 4.5 which I think is the one I use on Windows 8 RTM.

So am I doing something wrong ? Did I forgot to include some references ? Or is the documentation uncorrect ?

Thank you

Comment: You say you use Windows 8 RTM. Are you sure you didn't mean "Windows RT"? Because that is something else.

Comment: It looks like he's using WinRt on Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: What type of VS template did you use?

Comment: Ok I edited for the tag. The things that I don't understand is why there are those two pages : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage. There are describing the same thing and it is said that Windows 8 is supported on both.

Comment: I am using VS2012 last version

Comment: @AstironNaviir See my answer below.  One is for Win32 (i.e. desktop) and the other is for Windows Store Apps (i.e. metro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 has two separate platforms: WinRT and Win32.  WinRT is the tablet interface while Win32 is the traditional desktop.  See [here](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/Windows8DevelopmentPlatformClarified.aspx) for a diagram and explanation.  WPF only works for win32.

If you want the documentation for WinRT apps (or Windows Store Apps or Windows 8 UI Applications as they're also known) you need to look at [Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx) instead of [.NET Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2).

Comment: Ok I do understand the difference and I was looking at the right documentation. But I am developing a Windows Store App, and I am using the 4.5 version of the .Net framework. So why can't I use this class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx when it says that it is 4.5 Net framework compatible?  I know it is not the right documentation but is the framework different aswell?

Comment: @AstironNaviir That's correct.  The WinRT framework is not the same as the standard .net 4.5 framework.  There are a lot of APIs which are not available in Windows Store Apps which are available for desktop apps.

Comment: Ok thank you. That is just strange they put the same name and the same version number (I checked and it is 4.5.0.0). So those classes I was talking about were available in WPF and will only be available in windows 8 if I develop a software not a modern UI App, right ?

Comment: Correct.  That will only be available for desktop applications.